# I changed the "Int.TryParse" to while and now my code is not working

Tags: c#, console, while-loop

```
//the code  
parseAttempt = while (KeyBoardInput, out Response);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: //it says cannot implicity conver type string to bool    KeyBoardInput = Console.ReadLine();
parseAttempt = int.TryParse(KeyBoardInput, out Response);

Comment: Can you post the full code for this function?

Answer (score 6):

You can't *replace* `int.TryParse` with a while loop, but you can use it *with* a while loop as follows:

```
string keyboardInput = Console.ReadLine();

int response;
while (!int.TryParse(keyboardInput, out response)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input, try again.");
    keyboardInput = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Another approach is to refactor the code into a separate method:

```
int readIntFromConsole()
{
    while (true)
    {
        string keyboardInput = Console.ReadLine();

        int result;
        if (int.TryParse(keyboardInput, out result))
        {
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input, try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't keyboardInput be unassigned for the first pass?